# How can I dynamically target a Div that is also created dynamicaly and has a unique ID?

Tags: javascript

I'm extremely new to javascript and I need some help. What im trying to do is press a button, and then this button creates a div (with unique ID) and inside the div is also paragraph of text (also with unique ID) and a button to edit the content of that div. Every time the button is clicked it should make a new div with a paragraph (both with new unique IDs; div1, div2, div3 etc).

I cant seem to get it working because; when I create the new div, and attempt to put the paragraph inside that div, i cant get getElementbyID working. I use a counter++ to get the unique div ID name, so the div's ID name is = "divGod" + counter.

After that i attempt to use; document.getElementbyID("divGod" + counter).append child but it doesnt seem to be working. In my mind it makes sense that is should work but im very new and i dont know why its not.

I also dont want to do the method of:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML = "<p>nsdcvjnvso vsvos</p>
```

because this method produces some other errors im not able to fix.

So basically I create a DIV and give it uniqueID with counter:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute("id", 'divGod' + counter);
counter ++;
```

and later I try to target the newly created DIV with:

```
document.getElementById('divGod'+counter).appendChild(newP);
```

If i target other div that is there already, then the div gets created and the paragraph is outside of the div.

Basically I want to make a person input a text, I write out that text in a paragraph in a new div, and there would also be a button to change the inputted text.

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve what im trying to do?
Thank you

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 150px;"></div>
    <div>
        <input list="browsers" id="newTask">
        <datalist id="browsers">
            <option value="Internet Explorer">
            <option value="Firefox">
            <option value="Google Chrome">
            <option value="Opera">
            <option value="Safari">
          </datalist>
        <button onclick="createP ()">Klikni</button>
    </div>

    <div id="container-p" style="width: 1000px; margin: auto;">
         <h1 id="mojHeader">Moje Radnje</h1>
    </div>

<script>
    var counter = 0;
    function createP() {
      var input1 = document.getElementById("newTask");
            
      // novi div
      var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.setAttribute("id", 'divGod' + counter);
      counter ++;
   
  

      // isprintaj div
      document.getElementById("container-p").appendChild(newDiv);


    // novi paragraph
    var newP = document.createElement ("p");
    newP.innerHTML = input1.value;
    newP.id = "radnja-1";
    newP.className = "radnja-1";

// dodaj novi paragraf sa counterom
    var newP2 = document.createElement("p");
    newP2.innerHTML = counter;

// dodaj opet nešto
    
    
// egzekucija
    document.getElementById('divGod'+counter).appendChild(newP);
    document.getElementById("container-p").appendChild(newP2);
    document.getElementById("newTask").value="";

 
    }

    

</script>




<style>
.radnja-1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#container-p {
    justify-content: start;
    text-align: justify;
}

#mojHeader {
    display: block;
}

</style>









</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    

    <div style="height: 150px;"></div>

    <div>
        <input list="browsers" id="newTask">
        <datalist id="browsers">
            <option value="Internet Explorer">
            <option value="Firefox">
            <option value="Google Chrome">
            <option value="Opera">
            <option value="Safari">
          </datalist>
        <button onclick="createP ()">Klikni</button>
    </div>

    <div id="container-p" style="width: 1000px; margin: auto;">
         <h1 id="mojHeader">Moje Radnje</h1>
    </div>
  


<script>

    var counter = 0;

    function createP() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById("newTask");
    

    
// novi div
      var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.setAttribute("id", 'divGod' + counter);
      counter ++;
   
  

// isprintaj div
document.getElementById("container-p").appendChild(newDiv);


// novi paragraph
    var newP = document.createElement ("p");
    newP.innerHTML = input1.value;
    newP.id = "radnja-1";
    newP.className = "radnja-1";

// dodaj novi paragraf sa counterom
    var newP2 = document.createElement("p");
    newP2.innerHTML = counter;

// dodaj opet nešto
    
    
// egzekucija
    document.getElementById('divGod'+counter).appendChild(newP);
    document.getElementById("container-p").appendChild(newP2);
    document.getElementById("newTask").value="";

 
    }

    

</script>




<style>
.radnja-1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#container-p {
    justify-content: start;
    text-align: justify;
}

#mojHeader {
    display: block;
}

</style>









</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are adding id "divGod0" then target "divGod1".

Answer (score 0):

Use `insertAdjacentHTML()` method and make it easier.

```js
let element = "<div id='div-" + i + "'><p id='p-" + i + "'>" + paragraphContent + "</p></div>";
parent.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", element);
```

More readable:

```js
let element;
element = "<div id='div-" + i + "'>";
element += "<p id='p-" + i + "'>";
element += paragraphContent;
element += "</p>";
element += "</div>";
parent.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", element);
```

Comment: Both code snippets have errors

Comment: I didn't add HTML code. Here's full example: https://jsfiddle.net/3bx17hdc/